# g_mass_storage on rpi zerow is readonly (Use as Usb Stick)

Tags: raspbian, usb, pi-zero-w, storage

Heyho, i have a tiny problem, i will use the rpi zero w as device to submit space on my nas as USB Stick, for test i used local file only.

I used this tutorial withouth the samba things https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/pi-zero-w-smart-usb-flash-drive/ and i added the option "removable=1"

the "Stick" works and i get access to files in this file but i always have the problem "its write protected" so i cant add files from windows explorer on it, not really good when u want is as Usb Stick

I use last raspian and did rpi-update

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
sudo modprobe g_mass_strorage file=/path/to/file removable=1 ro=0 stall=0
```

The important part is the `ro` flag which has to be set to 0.

Comment: strange, now its workingy thx, i was sure doing the same but in different param pos

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working adding some lines to the modprobe:

```
sudo modprobe g_mass_storage file=/piusb.bin stall=0 ro=0 removable=1\
  idVendor=0x0781 idProduct=0x5572 bcdDevice=0x0126 iManufacturer="SanDisk"\
  iProduct="Cruzer Switch" iSerialNumber="4C597515973308202393"
```

I am able to mount it and share it via SAMBA, But there are conflicts between the two owning the same file system. I was hoping to be able to use it a little like a shared drive, and delete files remotely via SAMBA, but that might be asking a lot.

Answer (score -1):

I tried using following it, but it is missing steps. here is the one I used which works, aside from the issue I am having.

http://www.dlightsound.com/tutorial/USB-stick_on_a_Raspberry_Zero_W.pdf

Comment: Please post the relevant information here.  Answers consisting only of links are not very helpful and are likely to be deleted.

Comment: Please consider following Chenmunka's advice. Link-only answers may be deleted.